# How to prove it is a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Assume that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $B(x,r)$ be a ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$. By Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem, 
$$    \lim_{r\to 0} \dfrac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy=f(x)$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ almost everywhere. Assume that $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a point that such that $f(x_0)$ is finite and such that the equality above holds. Define

$$F(r):=\dfrac{1}{m(B(x_0,r))}\int_{B(x_0,r)}f(y)dy.$$ Is  $F(r)$ a continuous function of $r$ on $(0,+\infty)$? I think so but I’m not sure how to prove it. I tried to prove it by writing the definitions but feel completely stuck. Here’s some of my attempts.

By Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem, 
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} F(r)=f(x_0)<\infty.$$
And 
$$\lim_{r\to +\infty} F(r)= \lim_{r\to +\infty} \dfrac{1}{m(B(x_0,r))}\int_{B(x_0,r)}f(y)dy\le \lim_{r\to +\infty} \dfrac{1}{m(B(x_0,r))}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)dy
= \lim_{r\to +\infty} \dfrac{1}{m(B(x_0,r))}\cdot \Vert f\Vert_1=0.$$

Could you give me some ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is  a ratio of two continuous functions. Note that $m(B(x,r))=r^{n} m(B(0,1))$. To show that the numerator is continuous use the following facts:

For any integrable function $f$ , $\int_E f(x)dx \to 0$ as $m(E) \to 0$

$|\int_E f(x)dx - \int_F f(x)dx | \leq \int_{E\Delta F} |f(x)| dx$.

$m(B(x,r+h)\Delta B(x,r))=|(r+h)^{n} -r^{n}| m(B(0,1)) \to 0$ as $ h \to 0$.

Notation: $A \Delta B=(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand the definition of $A\Delta B$ correctly. Is that $(A\setminus (A\cap B))\cup(B\setminus (A\cap B))$ or equivalently $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$?

Comment: Yes, $A \setminus B$ is same as $A \setminus (A \cap B)$. This is the set of points that belong to $A$ but not to $B$. @Benny

Comment: Thanks! I get it!